# Azure - How to fix "Web application should only be accessible over HTTPS" warning?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-configuration

In an Azure app service > security, the following warning is displayed:

[image: Azure security warning]

**Question**
How to set the application for https only?

**Already tried:**

- edit the web.config in app service editor (XML) to create a redirection rule, which seems to be working but not removing the warning
- enable https only in custom domains (off -> ON)
- found a setting in an ARM template that seems to be related to this, but cannot edit template for the existing app
- looked for a solution in appsettings.json (not found)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go via Advisor - Security, you can click on the recommendations to see Description, General information, Threats and Remediation Steps.

For your recommendation, this is available:

> **Remediation steps**
>   To redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, we recommend the following steps:
>   1. Go to the app service custom domains page
>   2. In the HTTPS Only toggle select On

I can imagine recommendations wil not be update right away. Besides a statement these are held in cache somewhere, I could not find any documentation on how often recommendations are refreshed.

**Update** - found this:

> Advisor relies on backend telemetry to update its recommendation list. There will always be some delay between resolving a recommendation and seeing it removed from the list. If more people also feel strongly about this issue, we can prioritize accordingly.

More information at [Allow the ability to refresh Advisor recommendations](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919474-azure-advisor/suggestions/36968887-allow-the-ability-to-refresh-advisor-recommendatio)

Comment: Indeed, it has. Took hours, though. Thanks!